How to define a line in 3d space in terms of $\rho, \theta$, and $\phi$?
I have been struggling recently to come up with a solution for parameterizing a line to be swept by a vector in spherical coordinates.
More specifically, imagine a line segment defined in the form $\vec{\textbf{o}}+t\vec{\textbf{d}}$. How would one map such a line to a range of ($\theta,\phi,\rho$)? I already know there is a way to convert a point in cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates, but I am looking for a continuous function.
The tangential end goal is to be able to determine which ranges defined by $\theta$ and $\phi$ cover a non-axis-aligned quadrilateral.
Regardless, here is a Desmos demonstration of the problem:
https://www.desmos.com/3d/c2qkmjgtlw
Edit - further explanation:
The quadrilateral I am trying to define in spherical coordinates is composed of four cartesian points. My goal is to be able to determine the intervals of $\theta$ and $\phi$ over which a cone of angle $\theta_a$ covers a quad. Here is a revision which more closely aligns with my problem:

For an arbitrary quadrilateral defined in 3d, cartesian space and a right, circular cone defined by the angle $\theta_a$ with an apex at the origin, what are the ($\theta,\phi$) intervals over which the cone passes through the quad?

Edit - clarification:
I am looking to define which range(s) of theta and phi (could be any number of ranges, depending on the circumstances) cover the quadrilateral, edge inclusive. The quadrilateral does not have to be "inside the cone." That problem would be significantly easier to solve. The quad necessarily lies along one plane. Here is an example of a case I am looking to solve:



"Covers" or "passes through"? Does the entire quadrilateral have to be inside the cone? Does the cone have to pass through the quadrilateral without touching the edges? Or are you just looking for some part of the cone to pass through the quadrilateral? Is the quadrilateral all in one plane? Do you expect to find one range for $\theta$ and one range for $\phi$, and if so, what should we do if the range of $\theta$ depends on the range of $\phi$?

With the clarification, I think I understand what is asked. So the question is essentially whether there is any intersection at all between the cone and the interior and edges of the quadrilateral. That is a challenging question but well defined.

@DavidK I don't know if I explained it well enough. I have another function, in terms of  and , which I want to integrate over the area where the cone intersects the quad. I thought that, if I can get the intervals of  and  which define the intersection area, I can solve the integral of the spherical function.

The second diagram helps a lot. Somehow I did not realize before that the axis of your spherical coordinates is also the axis of your cone. Now I see why you would want to use spherical coordinates. I also see what you meant by "ranges" of coordinates: you can partition the area of interest into one or more double integrals. For some of these the outer integral might be over $\phi$ and the bounds of the inner integral might be a function of $\phi$.

Arguing from your graphs, I set the coordinate center as the center of the depicted circle (sphere) and as well as the origin of the line segment description.
If the  apex of your cone is at position $p$ on  the x-axis and if the cone has angle $\theta_a$, then the radius of the blue ball is $r = p \sin \theta_a$.
Now suppose the line segment is $\vec{\textbf{o}}+t\vec{\textbf{d}}$ where $0 \le t \le 1$. For restricting this line segment to be passed by the cone, there have to be two intersections of the cone and the line segment. It there is no intersection, the line segment is completely outside or inside of the ball, if there is one intersection, the line sticks in the ball or is tangential.  So the solution(s) to these intersections are given by $(\vec{\textbf{o}}+t\vec{\textbf{d}})^2 = r^2 =  p^2 \sin^2 \theta_a$. The solutions are
$$
t_{1, 2} = \frac{- \vec{\textbf{o}}\vec{\textbf{d}} \pm \sqrt{(\vec{\textbf{o}}\vec{\textbf{d}})^2 - \vec{\textbf{d}}^2 (\vec{\textbf{o}}^2 -  p^2 \sin^2 \theta_a)}}{\vec{\textbf{d}}^2}
$$
The six solution options for this equation are:

The argument of the root is negative: no intersection
The argument of the root is zero: line is tangential, if $t \in [0, 1]$: tangent segment touches the ball
The argument of the root is zero: line is tangential, if $t \not\in [0, 1]$: tangent segment outside the ball
The argument of the root is positive and only one of  $t_{1, 2}$ is  $\in [0, 1]$: one intersection, line segment sticks in ball
The argument of the root is positive and none of  $t_{1, 2}$ is  $\in [0, 1]$: no intersection, line segment outside of ball
The argument of the root is positive and both $t_{1, 2} \in [0, 1]$: two intersections of segment with ball

After having cecked that, we need to consider  only case 6 where there are two intersections with the respective $t_1$ and $t_2$, leading to two points $\vec A, \vec B $. Now to parametrize the line segment on the ball's surface, the information of the one straight line segment is not sufficient, since there are several projections of a line on a ball with two fixed points.  What is needed first is the same treatment of the other lines,  coming up with more intersection points to form a plane. Your quadrilateral must indeed be plane and not twisted.  Then a third point  $\vec C$ would do.
Now we are in a position to fix a plane from  three points, knowing that this plane intersects the ball. Since we have three points $\vec A, \vec B, \vec C$, then the normal vector of this plane is the cross product $\vec n=(\vec B-\vec A)\times(\vec C-\vec A)$, the normal distance of  the plane to the origin is  $d = \frac{\vec A \vec n }{|\vec n |}$, and the radius of the intersecting circle is $R = |\vec A  - \frac{d}{|\vec n |} \vec n |$. Vectors on the  intersecting circle are given by all points $\vec x$ with    $\vec x \vec n =  |\vec n |  d$ and   $\vec x^2  = \vec A^2 $ which is of course satisfied for $\vec A$ and   $\vec B$.
Answering your question now requires translating this last finding into spherical coordinates which can be done directly: $r = |\vec A|$ and
$ \frac{ \vec A \vec n }{|\vec A|}=\frac{|\vec n |  d }{|\vec A|}= (n_x x + n_y y + n_z z)/r = n_x \sin \theta \cos \phi + n_y  \sin \theta \sin \phi + n_z \cos \theta $. The second equation is implicit,  you can make it an explicit function $\phi = \phi(\theta)$ by isolating $\cos \phi$, squaring, applying  $\cos^2 \phi =1 -  \sin^2 \phi$, and solving the quadratic equation for  $\sin \phi$.
Finally, the segment of this circle you are interested in are all those values $(\theta, \phi)$ which lie between the points $\vec A$  and $\vec B$. Calculate the values $\theta_{A,B}$ for the points $\vec A$  and $\vec B$ by the usual formulae for spherical coordinates. So the segment of the circle are the points with parameters $\theta_1 < \theta < \theta_2$ where $\theta_{1,2}$ are the $\theta_{A,B}$, however it has to be checked in which direction your line segment runs.  The corresponding $\phi$ are given from  the explicit (or implicit) second equation.

A line is defined by $$\vec f=\vec a_0 +b_{scale}\vec b \tag{Eq.1}$$.
There are two main definitions of spherical coordinates.  Further $x=\rho\cos\left(\theta\right)\,sin\left(\phi\right)$,
$y=\rho\sin\left(\theta\right)\,sin\left(\phi\right)$
and $z=\rho\cos\left(\phi\right)$.
Partial Solution of a Line Through the Origin
A line through the origin is easy to solve for.  Just set $\theta=\theta_{constant}$ and $\phi=\phi_{constant}$.  Let $\rho$ vary, and the line passes through the origin.
The same thing can be done using the Equation from Equation 1:
$$\vec f -\vec a_0 = b_{scale} \vec b \tag{Eq. 2}$$
That is since when $b_{scale}=0$ then $\vec f - \vec a_0$ also passes through the origin, meaning that then from Equation 2, then by determining $\vec b$ as varying $\rho$ and constant $\theta$ and $\phi$ can also be applied because $\vec f - \vec a_0 = 0$ there.  Now the complication of how to add vectors from Cartesian Coordinates to spherical coordinates appears more difficult, the symbolic form of the line in Spherical Coordinates is very simple.
I am still reviewing the problem so for now I am setting my answer as a Community wiki.

Here are my inputs. Though I am not entirely sure what you want , I am going by the title.
"I already know there is a way to convert a point in cartesian coordinates to spherical coordinates, but I am looking for a continuous function."
We can easily extend that to lines.
In Cartesian Co-ordinates , the line in 3D will have the 3 Parametric Equations :
$x=x_o+at$ , $y=y_o+bt$ , $z=z_o+ct$ , where $(x_o,y_0,z_0)$ is a Point on the line & $t$ is the Parameter , while $a,b,c$ are indicate the Direction of the vector.
We can convert these to Spherical Co-ordinates with these Equations :
$x=\rho \sin \phi \cos \theta$
$y=\rho \sin \phi \sin \theta$
$z=\rho \cos \phi$
When we solve that , we will get :
$\rho = \sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2}$
$\theta = \arccos [z/\rho]$
$\phi = \arctan [y/x]$
Thus , line im 3D will have these Parametric Equations :
$\rho = \sqrt{(x_0+at)^2+(y_0+bt)^2+(z_0+ct)^2}$
$\theta = \arccos [(z_0+ct)/\rho]$
$\phi = \arctan [(y_0+bt)/(x_0+at)]$
Parameter is still $t$ here.
These are continuous functions which have certain ranges.
Using limits via calculus & real analysis , we can evaluate the over-all ranges , minimas & maximas.
When we have the Quadrilateral , we can re-evaluate the restricted ranges , minimas & maximas within the Area of Interest.
